# How to automate graphs using Selenium, Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I inject data into a web application and it generates a graph and a pie chart. I'd like to test the result on the graph is coherent with the given data through Selenium. Any ideas? Thanks, Best regards !!!

Comment: If your application provides the graph and pie chart as an image. Then it is not possible to automate through selenium.

Comment: Do you see how all over the place these answers are? That's because you haven't provided sufficient information for anyone to help you. It would help if you include extracts of your DOM to see how you can use Selenium effectively to extract data from the document model and compare it with your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your graph has a Javascript Model (e.g. an array) you can assert the contents of such array by using the assertEval command.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the most basic but fundamental example for your Pie chart problem,
Here I am taking Yahoo's YUI based PIE Chart for my example.
Here in each refresh all the sections are created dynamically so I am using contains in the id of the element . Here in the chart the controls are not simple HTML but these are svg (HTML5 controls) so on finding these we need to use //* in xpath.

My motive here is to find these dynamic sections in the PIE chart(Here in the current chart there are 5 sections)

And to click each section and to print tool tip text of these.

The Out put will be like.
Violette Part:day: Monday
taxes: 2000

Grey Part:day: Friday
taxes: 2000

Light Violette Part:day: Thursday
taxes: 200

Green Part:day: Wednesday
taxes: 4000

Brown Part:day: Tuesday
taxes: 50
0.61%

Here is the Demo program for it,anywhere you can execute it... :)

```
 package tests;

 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
 import org.openqa.selenium.By; 
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
 import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


 public class testCode {
 public static WebDriver driver;

 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

 driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.get("http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/charts/charts-pie.html");

 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

 **//FIND DIFFERENT SECTIONS IN PIE CHART**

 WebElement ViolettePart = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*   [contains(@id,'yui_3_13_0_1_')][contains(@class,'yui3-svgSvgPieSlice')][@fill='#66007f']"));
 WebElement GreenPart = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'yui_3_13_0_1_')][contains(@class,'yui3-svgSvgPieSlice')][@fill='#295454']"));
 WebElement GreyPart = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'yui_3_13_0_1_')][contains(@class,'yui3-svgSvgPieSlice')][@fill='#e8cdb7']"));
 WebElement LightViolettePart = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'yui_3_13_0_1_')][contains(@class,'yui3-svgSvgPieSlice')][@fill='#996ab2']"));
 WebElement BrownPart = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'yui_3_13_0_1_')][contains(@class,'yui3-svgSvgPieSlice')][@fill='#a86f41']"));

 **//TOOLTIP OVER PIE CHART**

 WebElement ToolTip = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id,'_tooltip')]"));

 **//CLICK EACH SECTION OF PIE CHART AND GET THE TEXT OVER IT**

 ViolettePart.click();
 System.out.println("Violette Part:"+ToolTip.getText());
 GreyPart.click();
 System.out.println("Grey Part:"+ToolTip.getText());
 LightViolettePart.click();
 System.out.println("Light Violete Part:"+ToolTip.getText());
 GreenPart.click();
 System.out.println("Green Part:"+ToolTip.getText());
 BrownPart.click();
 System.out.println("Brown Part:"+ToolTip.getText());
 } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are ok with just verifying metadata about the chart (captions, some JSON properties, etc) you will have to use image comparison. You define a baseline image that represents what the result should like like and your test compares against the reference.

Since it is not trivial to reliably test images you can use a library such as [Ocular](https://github.com/vinsguru/ocular).

Answer (score 0):

If it is a bar graph then you can identify all bars and the labels using "findElements", then you can iterate among the labels, get the label text if the text matches with the input that you have given then using Actions class move on that bar, then you can validate the data on the tooltip.

To get any xpath from the graph, you can use the * in you xpath in place of tagname for example

//*[@class='ABC']

you can follow the same process for pie chart but it is going to have few modifications